# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY error during event creation by trigger

Tags: event, calendar, insufficient-privileges

I have a trigger on Holiday (custom) object which automatically creates Calendar Event records for each users of Holiday creator's market.
But for one user I am getting an error like

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id:[]

Please note: The impacted user is above in the Role Hierarchy of the Holiday Creator. Can anyone tell me what can be the reason?

Comment: Can you go through the below article to get an idea of what the issue might be. http://www.forcetree.com/2011/12/insufficientaccessoncrossreferenceentit.html

Comment: Have you checked the user's profile and permission set?  Also your question is not clear -- what is "holiday creator market" and how are users related to it?